# Android Firebase: Why doesn't onMessageReceived() run when notification sent?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've searched through hundreds of stackoverflow posts and they all seem to suggest what i'm doing is correct.

**onMessageReceived:**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    
    private String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
          
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }
}
```

I have deployed a **Node JS script** on Firebase:

```
const payload =  {
                "data": {
                    "test": "worked",
                    "title": "Sidekick",
                    "body": `${senderName}: ${message}`,
                    "icon": "ic_sentiment_very_satisfied_black_24dp",
                    "click_action": "MESSAGE_ACTIVITY"
                }
            };
```

The user can receive notifications fine if I just use the "notification" tag, but when I try to do it the other way nothing happens. Even the MESSAGE_ACTIVITY runs when using "notification".

**The issue is I need to retrieve some information from the payload**, and apparently that can only be done by just using "data".

I expect android to log the data from the remote message, however it outputs nothing.

I have also tried adding a "to" property using the sender ID, but no luck.

I am also certain the script is running because I am logging to the Firebase function logs.

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending this payload to the right fcm token user?

Comment: I put the "to" property and used the Firebase ID of the user it should be sent to. That's the Firebase auth ID. Do I need to get an additional token somehow?

Comment: Can you pls attach the `correct` data (for `if I just use the "notification" tag`)? And FYI: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload

Comment: It's irrelevant because the "notification" tag works and doesn't affect the code in question

Comment: FCM doesn't uses UID as tokens if you are using them, FCM tokens are generated by the library and are different from the firebase auth UIDs.